# How to set atrribute defalutvalue system default image?

Tags: c#, image, default

I can't find c# winform default error image or null image address

how can find c# winform defalut null image?

```
[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true),
    System.ComponentModel.Category("Default"),
    System.ComponentModel.Description("Set thr first custom background Image"),
    ***System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(Image),"null")]***
    // Property for the background image to be drawn behind the button text. 
    public Image BackgroundImageBefore
    {
        get
        {
            return this.backgroundImage;
        }
        set
        {
            this.backgroundImage = value;
        }
    }
```

'

Comment: you can add image to your resource file and in your property field check if backgroundImage==null then asign your default image

Comment: I know your means, but I don't want user's resource image, I wnat System default image like including in shell32.dll

Comment: i think you have to assign your property it's not matter from where . use your image that's why i tell you to use resource .